# Facebook using FBSDKLoginButton showing different picture adding in storyboard and code

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk

I am using `FBSDKLoginButton` in my app, everything working well, only difference I found out that when ever I try to add the button using the code, it adds up Facebook login button with text "Login with facebook" and when ever I try to put the button through the storyboard it shows "Login" only.

I want to to put the button through storyboard, can I change the style to one which I get through code.

```
        let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        self.view.addSubview(loginView)
        loginView.center = self.view.center
        loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        loginView.addTarget(self, action: "loginFb:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: Can you put the code which add the button from the code.

Comment: @V.J. did you get any resolution?

Comment: i think it is not possible to change the title text for FBSDKLoginButton via code. I have searched a lot on google but didn't find any clue which tells it is possible. I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the size. If you increase the width enough it will update to the preferred style.

Answer (score -1):

First you define property to your .h file

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBLoginView *loginView;

and then take an UIButton in storyboard where you want to display 
and give class name as FBLoginView in inspector window set following property for UIButton
[image]

Comment: I think you did not get my question!!! I am not using FBLoginView. I am using FBSDKLoginButton. Its showing "Login with Facebook" if I am inflating using code however, if I make a button and set its class "FBSDKLoginButton" in storyboard. then call "FBSDKLoginButton.classForCoder()" in app dedelagate